# Trying to filter for two observation per condition

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
student_id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
test_score <- c(100, 90, 80, 100, 70, 90)
test_type <- c("English", "English", "English", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish")
time_period <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
df <- data.frame(student_id, test_score, test_type, time_period)
```

I am trying to filter my observations so that each student_id has a Spanish test and an English test. I have tried the following:

```
df <- df %>%
group_by(student_id, test_type) %>%
dplyr::filter(row_number() == 1)
```

But this seems to only return values from the English test. Is there a way to return single observations from each student_id for English and Spanish tests?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What is your criteria to choose one of the English test for one individual `student_id`? How do you handle the fact that `student_id` 1 doesn't have an Spanish test?

Comment: In your example data, student 1 only has English tests, and student 2 only has Spanish tests. Filtering on the condition that a student has both will leave you with an empty dataframe. Even if there were, which rows would you want to retrieve?

Comment: Or do you maybe want to remove duplicates, keeping only one row per student/test? In that case, which row do you want to keep if there are different values for the other columns?

Answer (score 0):

Your example data does not contain any student who has done multiple tests, i.e., filtering out only those that have done both English and Spanish will leave you with an empty dataframe. However, let's suppose the following is your data:

```
df <- data.frame(student_id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), 
                 test_score = c(100, 90, 80, 100, 70, 90), 
                 test_type = c("English", "English", "English", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish"), 
                 time_period = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
                 )
```

Here, student 2 has done both, and we wish to filter for all students who have done both types of exams. One approach is to look at each student and count the number of unique exam types. If that is larger than 1, then we found the relevant rows (including students who have completed three or more languages).

```
df %>% group_by(student_id) %>% 
  mutate(n_dist = n_distinct(test_type)) %>% 
  filter(n_dist>1) %>% 
  select(-n_dist)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   student_id [1]
  student_id test_score test_type time_period
       <dbl>      <dbl> <fct>           <dbl>
1          2         80 English             1
2          2        100 Spanish             0
```

This gives you all rows for student 2.

---

Having said that, it is a bit unclear what you wish to achieve, but if all you want is the first row per student x test_type combination, then your code does work. Another option is to use `slice`, as in:

```
df %>% group_by(student_id, test_type) %>% slice(1)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   student_id, test_type [4]
  student_id test_score test_type time_period
       <dbl>      <dbl> <fct>           <dbl>
1          1        100 English             1
2          2         80 English             1
3          2        100 Spanish             0
4          3         70 Spanish             1
```

Note I am using df as defined in my answer above.